# Using the Courtesan in multiplayer on PC

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

For a long time since I've been playing, I had the feeling that the **Courtesan** was just not a selectable character in multiplayer on the **PC**.  I *know* that console players have been able to choose her but it never seemed like PC players were able to.  Some people say that you need to be at level 50 so she would be unlocked -- I think they're talking about Brotherhood.  But I've seen videos of people less than 50 and were playing as **Courtesan** and I've already gotten past level 50 once and am currently at level 40 -- working my way to prestige -- and I have yet to be able to choose her.  She doesn't even appear in the roster as unlockable.  What gives?  I've seen similar questions on the net, all not really having a right answer as they answer from a console player's perspective.

Now, I've seen a player online and they were using the **Cortesan**!  They've prestiged once already (at level 48 and about to prestige again) so I'm guessing I *must* prestige once before she's available?  Or maybe it's just a coincidence since the first DLC has been out and she's a bonus?

Can anyone verify if this is true or know exactly when she may be used on PC?

Comment: You supposedly need Brotherhood installed and played a little bit online as mentioned [here](http://forums.ubi.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/5031067519/m/5441071769) but some PC users there claimed it doesn't work.  I agree.

Comment: Since the DLC came out, I'm seeing the Courtesan in the game much more now.  Coincidence?

Comment: The Courtesan is unlocked by having played AC:B multiplayer. Not sure how it tracks that on the PC, I'm guessing by signup to UPlay. Once of the new DLC characters (the Corsair) looks very similar to the Courtesan, has mostly the same animations. I often pick the Corsair if someone's picked the Courtesan (or vice versa) to make me harder to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She can only be unlocked if you have:

1. Played Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood
2. Linked your UPlay account for both games to the same account

From the wiki:

"The Courtesan can only be unlocked in Assassins Creed: Revelations if you have played Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood."

Comment: When i get the chance ill start up Revelations Multiplayer and see just how you unlock her (if you have to do something your self or if its automatic)

Comment: When I initially asked the question, I think the game was just bugged (among other things).  The following patches fixed the problems.